# QGIS 2.18 Couldn't Load QGIS Utils

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, osgeo

I ran into an issue and had to reinstall QGIS 2.18, but I can't seem to get it to properly work though. Whenever I install it it says "QGIS 2.18 is already installed on your computer..." even though I delete every possible reference to QGIS in the registry, my files, etc... I continuously get this error at startup:

```
    Couldn't load QGIS utils.
Python support will be disabled.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 21, in 
    standard_library.install_aliases()
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\future\standard_library\__init__.py", line 457, in install_aliases
    __import__(oldmodname)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\future\backports\__init__.py", line 17, in 
    from .misc import (ceil,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\future\backports\misc.py", line 24, in 
    from socket import getaddrinfo, SOCK_STREAM, error, socket
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.4\Lib\socket.py", line 47, in 
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.


Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

QGIS version:
2.18.3 'Las Palmas', 77b8c3d

Python path:
['C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Users/ac/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/ac/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.4\\Lib', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.4\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.4\\Lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\another-library', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.18\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg']
```

I've tried suggestions on similar posts but they're all from older versions of QGIS and are no longer relevant. I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it but I do also have Arc installed and I use that primarily. I know Arc installs Python a bit differently since it's native.

Comment: That ImportError usually means there is a 32bit vs 64bit python conflict. And looks like it's searching for python in both your ..\apps\lib\site-packages (QGIS) and C:\Python27 (ArcGIS)

Comment: Is there any way to change the path that it's looking in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Apparently with GDAL installed and directing it towards my ArcGIS Python path, Q wouldn't work.

EDIT: To fix this, I removed any GDAL environment variables and reinstalled QGIS. I'm not sure that the reinstall was necessary but I did it to be safe.

Comment: how did you fix it?

Comment: Please, add your solution

Comment: Could you post it as an answer and mark it as best answer? Or just edit the answer you posted before.